# How to increase the distance between table columns in HTML?

Tags: html, css, html-table, padding

Let's say I wanted to create a single-rowed table with 50 pixels in between each column, but 10 pixels padding on top and the bottom.

How would I do this in HTML/CSS?

Comment: You can not use margin between columns. You should specify a `width` or make use of `padding`.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

There isn't any need for fake `<td>`s. Make use of `border-spacing` instead. Apply it like this:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First Column</td>
    <td>Second Column</td>
    <td>Third Column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 50px 0;
}

td {
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

See it **[in action](http://jsfiddle.net/kp8jqfrn/3/)**.

Comment: The downside here is if you're striping rows or coloring them on hover: browsers won't extend the background color across the border space.

Comment: This is not the best answer: It leaves a space in the left of first column: [Refer this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37572153/2142994)

Answer (score 14):

Set the width of the `<td>`s to `50px` and then add your `<td>` + another fake `<td>`

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/MYwPt/)

```css
table tr td:empty {
  width: 50px;
}
  
table tr td {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First Column</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Second Column</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Third Column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Code Explained:**

The first CSS rule checks for empty td's and give them a width of 50px then the second rule give the padding of top and bottom to all the td's.

Comment: you didn't stated you want it for some columns!

Answer (score 12):

You can just use padding. Like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/davidja/KG8Kv/

**HTML**

```
   <table>
        <tr>
            <td>item1</td>
            <td>item2</td>
            <td>item2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**CSS**

```
 td {padding:10px 25px 10px 25px;}
```

OR

```
 tr td:first-child {padding-left:0px;}
 td {padding:10px 0px 10px 50px;}
```

Answer (score 9):

If I understand correctly, you want this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KG8Kv/1/).

```css
table {
  background: gray;
}
td {    
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-right:50px;
  background: white;
}
td:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello HTML!</td>
    <td>Hello CSS!</td>
    <td>Hello JS!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The fiddle attached to your post looks incomplete

Answer (score 8):

A better solution than selected answer would be to use border-size rather than border-spacing. The main problem with using border-spacing is that even the first column would have a spacing in the front.

For example,

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 80px 0;
}

td {
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First Column</td>
    <td>Second Column</td>
    <td>Third Column</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**To avoid this use: `border-left: 100px solid #FFF;` and set `border:0px` for the first column.**

For example,

```css
td,th{
  border-left: 100px solid #FFF;
}

 tr>td:first-child {
   border:0px;
 }
```

```html
<table id="t">
  <tr>
    <td>Column1</td>
    <td>Column2</td>
    <td>Column3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>3000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This makes a big white block. Wouldn't it be more sensible to use `padding-left` or `margin-left` instead?

Comment: The block doesn't have to be #fff. 'transparent' works fine.

Comment: Thanks. This also works to create an even gap between the table columns. I'm using it with a `width: 10vw` for my application.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
padding : 10px 10px 10px 10px;
```

Answer (score -2):

If you need to give a distance between two rows use this tag

```
margin-top: 10px !important;
```

Comment: not relevant, also you should not use !important without a very good reason to do so.