# How do I widen the gap between table colums? css-table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a simple table with two columns, I'd like to widen the gap between the columns. I've tried the column-gap property with no success. How can I widen the gap?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/daa4j43e/)

```css
      #t td {
        -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
        -moz-column-gap: 40px;
        column-gap: 40px;
      }
      #t tr:hover {
        background-color: #00FF00;
      }
      #t tr:first-child {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
```

```html
<table id="t">
  <tr>
    <td>Column1</td>
    <td>Column2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>2000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use border-spacing as shown in the answer by pseudoAJ. But the issue there is that you get a space on left/right of the table if you set a vertical border-spacing.

Hence a better option is to use border size.

For example, set `border-left: 100px solid #FFF;` and set `border:0px` for the first column.

```css
tr:hover {
   background-color: #00FF00;
 }
 tr:first-child {
   font-weight: bold;
 }

td,th{
  border-left: 100px solid #FFF;
}

 tr>td:first-child {
   border:0px;
 }
```

```html
<table id="t">
  <tr>
    <td>Column1</td>
    <td>Column2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>2000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: In practice I would recommend using a background color of #FFF0; (alpha of 0 so it is transparent) so that if you have any row hover color change effects (which you should for accessibility reasons) you don't see a white box like you do in the example. (however, it is good for the example so that you see what is going on)

Answer (score 4):

Use `border-spacing` property and add css for `table`. Here is the working example:

Demo: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/daa4j43e/2/)

```css
#t td {
  -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
  -moz-column-gap: 40px;
  column-gap: 40px;
}
#t tr:hover {
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
#t tr:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<table id="t">
  <tr>
    <td>Column1</td>
    <td>Column2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>2000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Further, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469483/how-to-increase-the-distance-between-table-columns-in-html) is a post that can help.

Comment: @rks This is not the best answer: [The extra space on the left](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37572153/2142994)